# Nouveau cursor "tearing"

Tags: xorg, cursor, nouveau

I am trying to find the proper terminology for the problem I am having so I can hunt down a solution.
I am using the nouveau driver. When the mouse pointer becomes a grabbing hand, a box forms around it that no longer shows the proper image on the screen. It shows the screensaver image (if one is set) or a black image (if there is no screen saver). It is as though the screen saver is behind the image of the desktop and I am getting a square box that tears through it to see behind the desktop.

My searches keep turning up vanishing cursors, cursors that don't move, cursors using the wrong image, etc... I cannot find anyone describing the problem of seeing through to the background around the cursor.

If this helps, this is a more technical description of what I am seeing, based on my understanding of how X works: When a part of the screen needs to be updated, a bounding box is defined that encompasses the area. X, eventually, updates the graphics in that area. As you move your mouse around, you tell X that it needs to redraw around your pointer - otherwise you would have a pointer smeared all over the desktop. For nearly all versions of the cursor (pointer, paragraph, scroll) this works fine. When I have a grabbing hand, such as the one when you mouse over Google Maps, the box is sent to X. Instead of updating it with the proper image, it is updating it with my screensaver image. Then, a second later, it updates it with the proper image. So, as I move my mouse over Google Maps, I see a square of my screensaver surrounding the little hand.